# MYSQL select all unique records by eliminating duplicate values by other column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, unique

I have table name graph

columns are : wwid_a,wwid_b, active, date_added

The values are

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| wwid_a | wwid_b | active |     date_added      |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|   1943 | 402158 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:51 |
|   1943 | 402209 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:52 |
|   1943 | 402464 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:52 |
| 402158 |   1943 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:5  |
| 402209 |   1943 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:59 |
| 402464 |   1943 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:58 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Basically each entry has duplicate record with column interchanged by wwid_a and wwid_b.

I want select query that will give each unique record eliminating duplicate value by alternate wwid_a and wwid_b

something like

```
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| wwid_a | wwid_b | active |     date_added      |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|   1943 | 402158 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:51 |
|   1943 | 402209 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:52 |
|   1943 | 402464 |      1 | 2014-03-05 09:08:52 |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Comment: The table do have records with the following data

Answer (score 2):

If, indeed, all are duplicated, then this might be the most efficient way to remove them:

```
select g.*
from graph g
where g.wwid_a < g.wwid_b;
```

If you are concerned that this might not *always* be true, then you have a couple of options.  The `not exists` logic might be best:

```
select g.*
from graph g
where g.wwid_a < g.wwid_b or
      not exists (select 1
                  from graph g2
                  where g2.wwid_a = g.wwid_b and
                        g2.wwid_b = g.wwid_a
                 );
```

That is, keep a row if the first record is smaller than the second.  Or, keep it if the matching less-than record doesn't exist.

This will work best on larger data with an index on `graph(wwid_a, wwid_b)`.

Comment: @Alnitak . . . Not only does the OP say this is true, but I even repeat that condition in the first sentence.

Comment: The table do have data like below +--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| wwid_a | wwid_b | active |     date_added      |
+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 1943   | alvarar3 | 1      | 2014-03-05 09:08:51 |
| alvarar3| 1943 | 1      | 2014-03-05 09:08:52 |

+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+

Comment: Can you modify query because wwid_a and wwid_b are not integers. The values are varchar2 For example. adamw2, vwilliams3, etc.

Comment: @user3384550 . . . This works fine on strings as well as numbers.  And dates and times too.